# Scopes in Angular not inheriting correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ApplicationController on the body tag. Inside this controller I am setting the username on a response from the server. Somehow the username variable is only available within the HomeController, which is currently not implemented.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="ApplicationController">
    Welcome {{username}}.
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

**home.html**

```
<div>You are logged in as {{username}}.</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('APP', [
  'ngRoute',
  'APP.services',
  'APP.controllers',
  'APP.auth'
])
.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');

    $routeProvider.when("/", {
      templateUrl: "/static/partials/home.html",
      controller: "HomeController"
    });

    return $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/"
    });
  }
);

angular.module("APP.controllers", ['ui.bootstrap.modal'])

.controller("HomeController", function($scope, $rootScope) {
})

.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope, $rootScope, USER_ROLES,
                                              AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService, $modal,
                                              UserService) {
  $scope.username = null;

  $scope.setCurrentUser = function(user) {
    $scope.username = user.username;
  }

  $rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, function(event) {
    UserService.get().then($scope.setCurrentUser);
  });
});
```

**Generated output**

```
<body>
  Welcome
  <div>You are logged in as AceUser</div>
</body>
```

### Update 1

If I select the ApplicationController element and then run `angular.element($0).scope()` I can see the scope and the username available. But still it is not output in the document.

### Update 2

The index.html was being generated with Django. Django was processing the template variable and not sending it as output. The solution was to wrap the variable with the {% verbatim %} tag. I will leave this up here for anyone who also has this problem.

Comment: you can use factory or services which allows you to share common datas between controllers

Comment: That would be good for organisation. But seeing that I can not access the scope, it would not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why it works in the HomeController.  I put together a working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VX2Uf7vtzfCCwdXFeHx4?p=preview) for you to compare your code with.

```
    angular.module('APP', [
   'ngRoute',
   'APP.controllers'
   ])
   .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when("/", {
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller: "HomeController"
    });

    return $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/"
    });
  });

angular.module("APP.controllers", [])

.controller("HomeController", function($scope, $rootScope) {})

.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.username = null;

  $scope.setCurrentUser = function(user) {
    $scope.username = user.username;
  }

  $scope.setCurrentUser({username: 'bob'});

});
```

Comment: Apart from removing dependencies, that is identical to my code.